# How to specify format when calling haml templates in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

In Sinatra, the following code

```
haml :index
```

Will render the file `index.html.haml` or `index.haml`

How can I specify file format? I been reading Sinatra README and trying different combinations but I can't see how to do it.

I need to be able to specify a haml template by giving its format too so I can do something like  `index.js.haml`.

Comment: It's right [there](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Haml%20Templates), isn't it?

Comment: Don't understand what you mean. What is precisely right there? What I'm not being able to do is specifying file format (html or js in this case).

Comment: Have you seen the `haml :index, :format => :html5` example in the docs that I linked to in my previous comment?

Comment: I think `:format => :html5` refers to something different. If I tried `haml :index, :format => :js` I'm getting this `Haml::Error at /
Invalid output format :js`

Comment: Looks like you're right. Sorry for misleading you.

Comment: `haml :'index.js'` Does this work? As per the source code, it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Kashyap points out

```
haml :'index.js'
```

That would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Found this while answering [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11343991/sinatra-error-when-handling-php-routes#comment14938283_11343991). [Sinatra-Respond_to](https://github.com/cehoffman/sinatra-respond_to). May be this is what you're looking for.