# Sinatra error when handling .php routes

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm creating a Sinatra app to replace a legacy PHP based app.

```
get '/page.php' do
  # ... do something
end
```

I'm trying to define a route like this but I get "Sinatra doesn't know this ditty." error page.

At the top of the page, I have this

```
configure do
  mime_type :php, 'text/html'
end
```

Any idea how to tell Sinatra to use the whole path including the file extension as part of it?

Comment: It's working fine for me. Even without the `configure` block. Did you make the same mistake of visiting `localhost:<whatever port>` and assuming it didn't work? I did. Then went on and opened up `localhost:<whatever port>/page.php` and it worked fine.

Comment: Screenshot: http://cl.ly/1o1b1t360H3r012s041T

Comment: I think its related that I'm using `require 'sinatra/respond_to'`

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to have proper Sinatra routes and do rewriting at the frontend web server?

Comment: @Martin Yes, that I think is the trouble. Use a `respond_to` block under the `get` block or else remove the `sinatra/respond_to` module entirely.

Comment: I have removed the `sinatra/respond_to` and now it works fine. Thanks!